# Make each user vote only once with Session username

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I made a simple vote poll it works fine,but i can't make it for each user i mean i can somehow hide if i even manage votepoll to be saved in users info but it's impossible when i tried insert into users it makes a new user with only votePoll declared...everything else is empty,i think it's a wrong way to approach,i can't even mind how to show votepoll whitch user is voteing.

This is my code of vote

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submitme'])){
    $submitme=$_POST['submitme'];
    $yesOrNo=$_POST['yesOrNo'];
    if(!empty($yesOrNo)){
        $sqlv=$con->query("INSERT INTO votepoll (yesorno) VALUES ('{$yesOrNo}')");
        header('location:index.php');

}
}

?>
```

Comment: you can record IPs. add a constraint to the table which forces uniqueness of IP addresses per poll and don't display anything to users if their ip is already listed for poll that they are looking at.

Comment: i want it with users bro,because if same user joins with another Ip he can vote so it's meaningless

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add your "yesorno" row in users,than make query update,don't insert!

```
if(isset($_POST['submitme'])){
$submitme=$_POST['submitme'];
$yesOrNo=$_POST['yesOrNo'];
if(!empty($yesOrNo)){
$sqlv=mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE users SET yesorno='$yesOrNo' WHERE username='$username'");
}
}
```

okay so when you click button yesorno is updated in rows as "yes" or "no" ,you should know how user statuses work, if($userStatus==1) and 1 is equal to Admin do so and etc. i'm just giving you direction now just get yesrno from rows and set it equal to variable and if("$userVote!="yes" && $userVote!="no"):
your html cde below and endif;
I just gave you some idea how to get through this problem and gave a direction.